# how to handle custom xml node properties using openxml 2.0 in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, openxml-sdk

xml schema:

```
<root>
  <IssueDate type="1753-01-01T00:00:00.000" Value="1753-01-01T00:00:00.000" />
  <JacketCode type="STLSC0H" Value="STLSC0H" />
  <Master type="" Value="" />
</root>
```

I am using above xml schema in the content control toolkit for mapping with word content controls.

Our application custom xml file having below xml code:

```
<root>
  <IssueDate> 25-01-92T00:00:00.000</IssueDate>
  <JacketCode>STLSC0H" </JacketCode>
  <Master> Ranga Rajesh </Master>
</root>
```

I changed word content controls values with custom xml values. Now my challenge is to format the IssueDate, JacketCode and Master. using below code i can change Master tag value but IssueDate and JacketCode values are not changing. Please help me in this regard. I have searched lot of sites i did not get any solution. please help me.

```
 using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(str, true))
        {
            var docPart = document.MainDocumentPart;
            string strData = string.Empty;
            var sdts = docPart.Document.Descendants<SdtRun>();

            foreach (var sdt in sdts)
            {
                SdtAlias alias = sdt.Descendants<SdtAlias>().LastOrDefault();
                string sdtTitle = alias.Val.InnerText;
                SdtRun xRun = (SdtRun)sdt;
                //Text xText = xRun.Descendants<Text>().FirstOrDefault();

                strData = sdt.SdtContentRun.InnerText;

                Text txt = new Text("Ranga Rajesh");
                var newtext = new SdtContentRun(new Run(new RunProperties(), txt));
                sdt.SdtContentRun.RemoveAllChildren();
                sdt.SdtContentRun.InsertAt(newtext, 0);

                //xText.Text = "xtext";
                docPart.Document.Save();
            }
      }
```

here my understanding is, in the xml schema IssueDate and JacketCode are having property values. how to handle that...

Please any one reply soon... i am still waiting for solution.